# how to troubleshoot the web app in web farm

Tags: asp.net

My webApp works fine on localhost, After it is deployed on web farm, I got random exception without any pattern. e.g. go to page 1 by menu, it is OK then goto page 2 do nothing and back to page 1, it is crash. there is DB access on each page. sometimes,the exception mesage was "attemped to read or write protected memory". the message confuses me all the time.  I heve no clue where to start to troubleshoot issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is [one possible solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/675515.aspx) documented on the ASP.NET forums.

What I would do is to setup a very simple ASP.NET page that accesses the database. Try to run this, and post the full exception message and stack trace that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "web farm," I'm assuming you mean a multi-server or multi-worker process deployment.  Some ideas for you:

1. InProc session state won't work in that scenario; switch to StateServer or SQL
2. Other types of per-server state management also won't work, including user-specific Caching
3. Consider writing custom errors to the Windows event log in the event of unexpected Exceptions
4. Consider walking through the way you handle cookies, and your "application policy" code, such as HttpModules
5. Consider using SQL Profiler to make sure SQL queries from all servers in the farm are as expected
6. Make sure you are using the same hard-coded machineKeys on all servers (for consistent ViewState handling)